# Amazon Kinesis Firehose as a cloudwatch logs consumer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

My requirement is to collect the VPC flow logs from AWS. I have created   a VPC flow log and associated it to cloud watch log group "Flow log group".
From CloudWatch logs subscription I thought of subscribing it through the AWS Kinesis firehose, but in the subscription list I could not find the "Kinesis Firehose", Only "Lambda" and "ElasticSearch Service". Could you please help me on this.

Cannot we subscribe the CloudWatch logs using AWS Kinesis firehose.

Comment: I believe you need to have the stream created before hand to associate the cloudwatch data to it

Comment: Hi Jonhn, Thanks for the quick reply. I have tried it by creating the kinesis steam first then I have created the VPC flow logs. After  that I tried to subscribe the AWS cloudwatch log group through kinesis firehose but in AWS cloud watch console I could not have option to subscribe the logs through the kinesis firehose.

Comment: Any luck on this? I am in the same boat.

Answer (score 8):

A Firehose arn is a valid subscription destination for CloudWatch Logs, but it is not possible to set one with the console, only with API or CloudFormation.

Most examples I have found use the console's LogGroup option 'Stream to AWS Lambda' to feed a AWS Lambda that forwards to Amazon Kinesis Firehose, such as in [How to Visualize and Refine Your Network’s Security by Adding Security Group IDs to Your VPC Flow Logs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-visualize-and-refine-your-networks-security-by-adding-security-group-ids-to-your-vpc-flow-logs/).

The [Using CloudWatch Logs Subscription Filters chapter of the Amazon CloudWatch Logs User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html) has a [Firehose Example (Example 3)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#FirehoseExample) that might be a better fit for your use case.

Essentially, the path is `Amazon CloudWatch LogGroup SubscriptionFilter -> Amazon Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream -> Amazon S3 Bucket and Prefix`

*Fun Fact: Amazon CloudWatch Logs data is already GZIPped when delivered to Firehose.*